# Related Radio buttons and Drop down list

Tags: javascript, php, list, radio-button, html-lists

i am trying to make a form, in which i have a number of radio buttons (created dynamically), and a drop down list.

In the drop down list i have numbers.
I want the drop down list to depend on the radio button currently pressed, meaning that, if i press the first button, the maximum number appearing in the drop down list will be a value x, if i press another radio will be a value y. This values represent a php variable.

What is the easiest way to do this thing?

Thank you!

Editing:

i tried:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #ca {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:radio").click(function() {
        $('.searchSelect').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).attr("value")).show();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="countrylist"> 
        <li> 
            <label for="US-country"> 
                <input name="store" id="US-country" type="radio" value="com" checked="checked" /> 
                USA</label> 
        </li> 
        <li> 
            <label for="CA-country"> 
                <input name="store" id="CA-country" type="radio" value="ca"/> 
                Canada</label> 
        </li> 
    </ul> 
    <select name="search-alias-us" id="com" class="searchSelect" title="Search in"> 
        <option value="aps" selected="selected">All Departments</option> 
        <option value="apparel">Apparel &amp; Accessories</option> 
        <option value="automotive">Automotive</option> 
    </select> 
    <select name="search-alias-ca" id="ca" class="searchSelect" title="Search in"> 
        <option value="aps" selected="selected">All Departments</option> 
        <option value="stripbooks">Books</option> 
        <option value="popular">Music</option> 
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

also included : the jquery 1.5 library . still, the drop down list does't change on radio button click.

thank you!

Comment: @Ian Moss what does that have to do with the question?

Comment: @Ian Moss: What are you talking about? This is not a Hindi Q&A site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question right but I once made something similar, what I did was output all dropdownlists and hid them with css then on clicking the radiobutton unhid the dropdownlist I needed using jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/6svcD/

It can be even shorter with show() and hide()

```
$(function() {
    $("input:radio").click(function () {
       $('.searchSelect').hide();
       $('#' + $(this).attr("value")).show();
    });
});
```

The whole page below or here: http://jsfiddle.net/MrAGF/1/

```
    <html>
<head>
<style>
    #ca {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:radio").click(function() {
        $('.searchSelect').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).attr("value")).show();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="countrylist"> 
        <li> 
            <label for="US-country"> 
                <input name="store" id="US-country" type="radio" value="com" checked="checked" /> 
                USA</label> 
        </li> 
        <li> 
            <label for="CA-country"> 
                <input name="store" id="CA-country" type="radio" value="ca"/> 
                Canada</label> 
        </li> 
    </ul> 
    <select name="search-alias-us" id="com" class="searchSelect" title="Search in"> 
        <option value="aps" selected="selected">All Departments</option> 
        <option value="apparel">Apparel &amp; Accessories</option> 
        <option value="automotive">Automotive</option> 
    </select> 
    <select name="search-alias-ca" id="ca" class="searchSelect" title="Search in"> 
        <option value="aps" selected="selected">All Departments</option> 
        <option value="stripbooks">Books</option> 
        <option value="popular">Music</option> 
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hello, the script seems nice on jsfiddle, and does what i need. i tried using it on my project, but it doesn't work there... the drop down list doesn;t change. i included the javascript script in the template, but... should i also include some libraries somewhere? whar i am missing ? how can i make that js little script onload to my radio button?   thanks a lot

Comment: It uses Jquery so you need to add that as well.  jsfiddle has that included by default.

Comment: sorry, i have included jquerym but still... no magic. the drop down list doesn't change at all...

Comment: seems like that little .js is not 'seen' by the radio, even though i insert in in the template, or in the current view. any ideas ?:)

Comment: could you add your code to jsfiddle? Would make it easier to spot where it goes wrong.  Do you have the right classes and ids set up?

Comment: i don't know how to use jsfiddle, but i will edit my question and add the code :)

Comment: Js fiddle has no instructions ;-)  you just open it add html to html pane, js to the js pane, css to the css pane then click run.  And select jquery on the left.

Comment: i see.. but i can only add the code given by you cause i did not modify a thing :D i have paste the code in my question. my dilemma is how to make the html code know about the little javascript code there...

Comment: I changed the code you pasted, try that now, you forgot the $(document).ready(function() {*jquerycode here*}); around the jquery script.  You could also use $(function() {*jquerycode here*}); instead, it's basically the same but shorter.

Comment: hmmm... still doesn't work, can't figure why. i have added the code around the .js but no results yet...

Comment: just copy/paste the entire code I added to my answer.  I tested it, that should work.